# Did not get all list of object in my controller using ajax but only one

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am sending list of items to my controller using ajax jquery.

I get list of items but not all I get only one item and which is at nr 2 in list.

javascript

```
$('#AddObject').click(function () {
    var CustomerKeysList = 
    [
        {
            CustomerId: '5',
            Name:'test1',
            DateCreated:new Date(),

        },
        {
            CustomerId: '3',
            Name:'test2',
            DateCreated:new Date(),

         },
         {
             CustomerId: '43',
             Name: 'test2',
             DateCreated: new Date(),

         },
    ]

    alert(JSON.stringify(CustomerKeysList));
    var i = $(".thingRow").length;
    var url = '/admin/customer/AddObject?index=' + i;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(CustomerKeysList),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
            $('#Table').append( '<tbody>'+ data).append('<button 
  id="AddObject1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Object</button>');
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            alert(a + " " + b + " " + c);
        }
    });
})
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult AddObject(int index, List<CustomerKeys> CustomerKeysList)
{
    return PartialView("_EmptyRow", CustomerKeysList);
}
```

When I click the button its send the list of CustomerKeysList but when I debug my controller I found only one item and its always send item.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help me I should be highly appreciable.

[Image shows the detail of list I got from ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoZuT.png)

Answer (score 2):

Change your script like below

```
var CustomerKeysList = [
    { CustomerId: '5', Name:'test1', DateCreated:new Date() },
    { CustomerId: '3', Name:'test2', DateCreated:new Date() }, 
    { CustomerId: '43', Name: 'test2', DateCreated: new Date() }
];
CustomerKeysList = JSON.stringify({ 'CustomerKeysList': CustomerKeysList}); // add this
```

and change data attribute as

```
data: CustomerKeysList,
```

So it may look like this

```
$('#AddObject').click(function () {
    var CustomerKeysList = [
        { CustomerId: '5', Name:'test1', DateCreated:new Date() },
        { CustomerId: '3', Name:'test2', DateCreated:new Date() }, 
        { CustomerId: '43', Name: 'test2', DateCreated: new Date() }
    ];
    CustomerKeysList = JSON.stringify({ 'CustomerKeysList': CustomerKeysList}); // add this

    var i = $(".thingRow").length;
    var url = '/admin/customer/AddObject?index=' + i;

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json', // you may need this
        data: CustomerKeysList, // change
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)
            $('#Table').append( '<tbody>'+ data).append('<button id="AddObject1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Object</button>');
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            alert(a + " " + b + " " + c);
        }
    });
})
```

and your controller

```
public ActionResult AddObject(int index, List<CustomerKeys> CustomerKeysList)
{
    return PartialView("_EmptyRow", CustomerKeysList);
}
```

Comment: great work . its working now you save lot of time for me.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted